# Making your discord bot save messages that you sent

Tags: javascript, json, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm working on my discord bot and I want it to save messages that i sent it to save, how do I do this since the rest of the internet doesn't ask this question for some reason. i've been looking for someone to point me in a direction but haven't found anything

Comment: Are you trying to log messages users send in servers your bot is in?

Comment: Not really, im trying to make it so that when you say ```+add "hello"``` it adds it to a list so when you put in ```+show ``` it will show the words you added

Comment: Maybe like create an array, and then just add the args[1] into the array. So +add "hello" would add "hello" into the array. When a user does +show, just send the items in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really simplified version of what you want to do but I'm sure if you read it you'll understand and it will get the job done.

```js
const discord = require('discord.js'); // Import discord.js

const client = new discord.Client(); // Initialize new discord.js client

const messages = [];

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith('+')) return; // If the message doesn't start with the prefix return

  const args = msg.content.slice(1).split(' '); // Split all spaces so you can get the command out of the message
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase(); // Get the commands name

  switch (cmd) {
    case 'add':
      messages.push(args.join(' ')); // Add the message's content to the messages array
      break;
    case 'get':
      msg.channel.send(messages.map((message) => `${message}\n`)); /* Get all the stored messages and map them + send them */
      break;
  }
});

client.login(/* Your token */); // Login discord.js
```